# The MSVC compiler thinks I am referencing a deleted function but as far as I can tell, I am not

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo &)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void operator=(const Foo &)
    {
        std::cout << "Asign operator" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo{};

    std::cin.get();
}
```

When I run this, the output is "Default constructor" and nothing else so I know that the only thing being called is the default constructor.

However if I change the class to this:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;

    void operator=(const Foo &) = delete;
};
```

The code will now fail to compile with this error:
[image: The error message]

The code will compile if I change the variable declaration to `Foo f{};`. Is there a way I can use the first style or is this just a thing I have to deal with?

Comment: You should compile with `/std:c++17` or newer. Otherwise even if copy constructor is being optimized away it is still required to be accessible.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `auto f = Foo{};` is copy initialization and before C++ 17 you had to have a valid move or copy constructor to make that "copy", even if the compiler optimized it away

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: Quick note, your `copy assignment` operator is not correct. It should be `Foo& operator =( const Foo& rhs );` Take note of the `return` value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a copy constructor when on this line:

```
auto f = Foo{};
```

Foo{} - creates an anonymous object 
auto f = ... - does copy the object into `f` variable

To avoid this, just use this code

```
Foo f;
```

Comment: No. Please god no. Initialize your variables. Always.

Comment: you do not need to initialize a variable if class of this object has a default constructor. So, the `Foo f;` is super valid expression.

I've seen a lot when people initialize variables where it is not necessary, for example:

    `std::string myString = "";`
    `std::string anotherString = std::string();`

Comment: Just because you don't _need_ to doesn't mean you shouldn't do it. Its a good practice to be in. Literally one extra keystroke, assuming you're using an IDE that will autocomplete braces for you. `Foo f{};`